# Reconstructing Missed Raycast Hit Positions using other Hit Positions?

Tags: geometry-nodes

My current raycasting conundrum involves a setup where I need to raycast project a grid over an arbitrary surface which I will later use to instance something on each face, and **I need to reposition (not remove) the points that overlap which you can see in the image below.**

[image]

The grid must encompass the entire surface of the mesh which means there will be points on the grid that either entirely miss or that hit geometry that isn't part of the surface.

These pieces of geometry I can identify and filter but the key piece of the puzzle I'm missing is working out how to **reposition these points so that their positions remain relative to the rest of the grid that did successfully hit.**

[image]

The above image shows the relevant part of the Geometry Node graph.  I have tried...

- Using a custom shrink/fatten node group on the raycast target to try to extrapolate the data (doesn't really work).
- Trying to isolate each face to see if I can make some manual corrections (didn't have any luck).
- Some other unhelpful dumb stuff.

I assume the solution would involve some kind of domain within domain filtering but after a lot of staring and tinkering I feel like a dog tangled in TV cables so any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

#### Edit

Upon request, here's some pictures of the behavior I'm trying to achieve against the result I currently get - the grid segments that didn't fully hit the surface need to be positioned by interpreting the normals of the points that did hit and making a best guess:
[image]
[image]

**You can download a demonstration of the issue below.**

[image]

Comment: could you please add a picture/image how your result should look like? thanks

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the interest, I've added additional photos.  If there's anything else you'd like that would help please let me know ^-^

Comment: Maybe rather than raycasting from the top, you want to raycast from a sphere towards the center and if the ray misses (goes past the center)? Unless you want to just have a small margin around the top surface, in which case maybe you could capture info on hitting or not, and as a next step check all neighboring vertices, and average their position with some logic.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady That sounds interesting but I'm having a hard time visualizing what you mean, could you explain it in a little more detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following I will describe three approaches. I consider the third one to be the best. But that may vary depending on the concrete application.

First I will give an overview about the solutions. Afterwards I will explain those solutions in detail.

## Overview

### Solution 1

This one covers the whole surface but does no repositioning

[image: result]

[image: node setup]

[image]

### Solution 2

This one does the repositioning. First, I thought, it needs only a little fine tuning to be perfect. But after trying around some time, it turned out, that there are to many corner cases, to get it working in all cases.

[image: result 2]

This corner is an example for a problematic corner case:

[image: issue]
[image: issue v2]

[image: node setup]

[image]

### Solution 3

This one uses a completely different but easy approach and simply works.

[image: result 3 video]

[image: result 3 image]

[image]

## Solutions explained

Following, I will describe the implementation of the solutions.

### Solution 1

First create a mask object from the surface by copying the top faces of the object.

[image: mask]

Next create a new object that holds the geometry nodes modifier. The geometry nodes take the mesh resolution, the target collection and a mask object as input.

[image: geometry nodes modifier parameters]

The mask object is flattened and extruded. Then, a mesh is created, that is large enough to cover the whole mask. This mesh is intersected with the extruded mask. Now we have this:

[image: grid]

After moving the mask on top of the target, we can then raycast it onto the target.

[image: final grid]

### Solution 2

The basic idea of this approach is, to use the mesh, that we created in solution one before we did the raycasting, to mark those points of a much larger mesh, that will hit the target. This way we can even identify those vertices, that have to be repositioned, because they will have a neighbour, that will hit the target. And all other vertices can be deleted.

Having this, we can use the target position of the hitting neighbours to calculate the position of those, that have to be repositioned.

### Solution 3

[image: result 3]

The basic concept for the final solution is really simple:

Start with separating the target geometry from the original geometry.

[image: Separate target geometry]

Extend it, so that it defines the shape and area of the point mesh. (I added the original geometry to the following picture, so that one can see the extension.

[image: Extend the target geometry]

Hide the target geometry. The target geometry will only be used to generate the raycasted mesh:

[image: original geometry with hidden target geometry]

Use geometry nodes to create a raycasted mesh on the hidden target geometry:

[image: The final grid]

#### Implementation

The major part of this solution is quite simple:

[image: node setup for raycasting]

This node setup is added to the grid object in the example file. It creates a mesh on top of the target geometry that has the same size in x- and y-dimensions as the bounding box of the target geometry.

Then this mesh is raycasted on the target geometry. All missing points are deleted.

Input parameters are a collection containing the target geometry and the resolution of the mesh in x and y.

##### Extending the target geometry

The rest depends on how you create the extended target geometry. You could do this manually or use a plugin. But I found, that the offset-edges plugin vanished in Blender 3.1. So I just had some fun, to create a node setup, which adds an offset to the border of the target geometry, while trying to preserve the original shape.

This surely has its limitations, which I will explain later. But it offers the ability to stay non-destructive. - And it is quite large, as you can see here:

[image: node setup for creating offset]

So, let’s take a look at the logic that is used for extending the target geometry. We consider the target geometry to be a surface. And we want to move the border of this surface away from the geometry, so that it grows. Additionally, we want it to grow by the same absolute amount on every side.

As a going in position, we select the border and order its vertices counterclockwise:

[image: Select and order border points]

We start with a simple example. In this example the surface is flat and we take a look at a convex/outward oriented corner. Where should we move the corner point and by which amount?

[image: convex corner example]

P is the corner point. We would like to move P coplanar to the touching face. Let $\vec{n_a}$ and $\vec{n_b}$ be the normalized vectors that are coplanar to the touching face, orthogonal to the touching edges and pointing away from the face. Then we would like to move P into direction $\vec{n_a} + \vec{n_b}$. We call the amount, that we want the border to grow by, *Offset Factor*. Furthermore, let P- be the predecessor and P+ be the successor point of P. Having this, we can calculate the length of the displacement vector of P. Here is the complete calculation of the displacement vector:

[image: Calculate displacement vector]

This formula works for all border points, not only for convex corners – as long as the surface is flat. There is only one thing, we have to solve: How can we access the predecessor and successor points of P? Here is the solution:

[image: Getting the neighbouring points]

We use the reordered border to determine the indices of the predecessor and successor points of every point. Then we save their positions at the point in the original border by using *Capture Attribute* nodes.

As already mentioned, this solution only works for flat surfaces. So, let’s take a look at the next example:

[image: example 2]

Here we have four connected faces and every face is aligned in a different angle. If we apply the above logic to this object, we receive this result (image shows original and modified geometry):

[image: example 2 after offset]

As you can see, the edges, that connect the faces changed and so did the whole original geometry. If we want to prevent this, we need to move the points into the direction, that is defined by the corresponding edge.
But this will bring some new limitations, as you can see by looking at the following example:

[image]

If you moved the both center points on the bottom outward along their edges, the edges would intersect each other soon. This is, why we want to limit this method to cases where the inner edge has an edge angle > 0.

Furthermore, we have to take into consideration, that a point may be connected to more than one inner edge. If multiple of those had an angle > 0 we don’t get around changing the original geometry. But we can minimize this, if we calculate the direction by adding the vectors of all edges weighted by their edge angle.

To realize this, we start with calculating the direction of the offset vector for every point of the border. We use the [Array Pattern](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262829/find-highest-index-value-for-each-mesh-island-is-it-possible-geometry-nodes) to store the result:

[image: Calculating the offset direction]

Based on the length of this vector we can determine for each point of the border, if it is connected to an edge with edge angle > 0. We use this to decide, which of both strategies we choose. If this one is chosen, we calculate the length of the vector:

[image: Calculating the length of the offset vector]

To sum it up, this solution works but has its limitations. And it would have been easier to preserve the original geometry by extruding the border than by setting it off.

##### Update: Just another way to extend the target geometry

Instead of setting the border of the target geometry off, we could kind of extrude it.

[image: result of extrusion]

Let N be the count of vertices of the border of the target geometry, then we start by creating a 2x(N+1) grid. Next, we wrap it around the border like this:

[image: wrapping video]

This way, we can preserve the original geometry in every case and it is easier to cope with those problematic corner cases. Anyway, the offset is still limited, due to the inner corners, that will lead to intersecting edges, when the extrusion is too large.

The node setup is still too large to be displayed in one image, so just take a look at the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Yeah! You did it again! If I had such a crazy question, I would immediately choose this crazy answer as Accepted ;-)

Comment: I need to poke at this a little before marking as the solution but it's clear that while not perfect Solution 2 is close which is impressive given the difficulty and specificity of the problem.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Takanu , I did some finetuning on solution 2 and updated the answer accordingly. But there is still one issue left. I have an idea of how to solve this and will give it a try. I will come back afterwards.

Comment: @AndréZmuda That's totally fine, even if you're not able to this provides a mechanism to getting to a watertight solution that I didn't have before which is unbelievably helpful.

Comment: @Takanu , I added another solution to my answer.

Comment: @AndréZmuda I'm going to need a bunch of time to pick apart the answer but the amount of thought and effort put into your approach is humbling and I can't thank you enough for the time you've spent to make this.  Getting the extension of the surface mesh in Geometry Nodes is also incredibly handy as non-destructive workflows is always a priority of mine ^-^

This fits a really important missing piece for a Blender to Unity workflow I'm designing, once i've gone through and integrated the solution i'll post it on the project's GitHub page (https://github.com/Takanu/Squeak)

Comment: @Takanu , don't worry, you did not waste my time ;-) - I just had some fun solving this. I'm happy if it helps. - And I added another way for extending the surface.